# Is the ArroundInvoke method gets invoked if it were invoked from another ejb method?

Tags: ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean, interceptor

I've  the following case:

```
@Interceptors(MyInterceptClass.class)
public void ejbMethod1()
{

}


@Interceptors(MyInterceptClass.class)
public void ejbMethod2()
{
    ejbMethod1();
}
```

Is calling ejbMethod2 causes TWO interceptor calls to be executed?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean the `@Interceptors` annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you mean `@Interceptors` (plural) annotation which defines the interceptor class which will be invoked upon annotated method invocation. `@Interceptor` annotation (singular) is for annotating a class which is an interceptor.

If so, then short answer is: **no**.

The interceptor is executed by the container. If your method invocation will not go through the container, then it **will not** be intercepted.

Therefore the following call to `ejbMethod1()`:

```
@Interceptors(MyInterceptClass.class) 
public void ejbMethod2() {
    ejbMethod1(); 
}
```

won't activate the `MyInterceptClass` as it's the local call (non-EJB one).

If you'd like to call the interceptor once again, you should use business interface, so something like:

```
// Somewhere in the class
@Resource
SessionContext ctx;

@Interceptors(MyInterceptClass.class) 
public void ejbMethod2() {
    // This is explicit call which will go through the EJB Container
    ctx.getBusinessObject(YourEJBClass.class).ejbMethod1();
}
```

This will make the EJB-aware call and will hit the interceptor while invoking `ejbMethod1()`.